# What is the Difference Between Whitespace and Empty String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am checking if the user input is left empty or not using my check like that:

```
function myFunction() {
    if(nI.value.length<1)
    {
        alert("Field is empty!"); 
        return false; 
    }
    else 
    {   
        return true; 
    }
}
```

where nI is the text input object.

I read in another place we can do that through:

```
function isSignificant( text ){
  var notWhitespaceTestRegex = /[^\s]{1,}/;
  return String(text).search(notWhitespaceTestRegex) != -1;
}
```

The last function is checking for whitespace. What is the difference between checking for empty string and whitespace?

Comment: First check if string length is not zero. This also considers a single space ` ` as valid string. Second, checks if there is at-least one non-space character.

Comment: The second test makes the first redundant, it would be simpler as `/\S/.test(nI.value)`. ;-)

Comment: @Tushar not sure what u mean

Comment: `if(nI.value.trim())` will work... `trim()` removes space on each end and an empty string is falsy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should know the difference between empty string and a white space.

The length of a white `' '` space is 1 .

An empty string `''` will have a length zero.

If you need to remove any number of white spaces at both starting and ending of a string you may use `trim()` function, then you may count the length if it is necessary.

OR

You may check for empty string after using `trim()`