# Alert box is not working in function while validating username and password using if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
    function validate() {
        var x=document.getElementById("user").value;
        var y=document.getElementById("pass").value;
        if(x==null || x==" ") {
            alert("Enter username");
        }
        if(y==null || y==" ") {
            alert("Enter password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some inspiration on how to write a question which will probably have some answers. Describing your expectation and your observation usually helps to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Twonky commented, we need some additional information. The code that you posted is just a function. I suppose you have two inputs and a button? Do you want the alerts to show when a user clicks the button and the input fields are empty? If you do, you need to add this function as a callback to onclick event.

More about the events:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events
>
> https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/onclick-javascript
>
> https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-make-button-onclick-in-html.html

Edit: added corrected code and some links for further reading. The mistake was with looking for white space, instead for an empty string (" ", instead of "")

```
<!doctype html> 
  <html> 
    <head> 
      <title>Welcome</title> 
      <script> 
        function validateForm() {
          var x=document.getElementById("user").value; 
          var y=document.getElementById("pass").value; 
          if(x==="" || x===null) {
            alert("Enter username");
            }; 
          if(y==="" || y===null) {
            alert("Enter password"); 
          };
        };
      </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
      <div> 
        Username:<input type="text" name="un" id="user"/>
        Password:<input type="password" name="ps" id="pass"/>
        <input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()"/>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Further articles about these topics:

[Stackoveflow thread about whitespace and empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886934/what-is-the-difference-between-whitespace-and-empty-string-in-javascript)

[An article about the difference between == and ===](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a)

P.S.: I had also **changed the element from *form* to *div***. Since you are using your function in this case as a security so the user wouldn't submit empty data, this is better for now, since *form* is submitted with your function call and *div* isn't. You can check the network tab to see, that the page reloads after the function is executed with *form* element and is not reloaded with the *div* element.

Comment: Hello Sir...This is my whole code which is not executing properly

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.getElementById("user").value;
var y=document.getElementById("pass").value;
if(x==" " || x==null){
alert("Enter username");
}
if(y==" " || y==null)
{
alert("Enter password");
}

}
 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Username:<input type="text" name="un" id="user"/>
Password:<input type="password" name="ps" id="pass"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ok, Vrushali, thank you for posting the entire code. It looks good, and I managed to get it to work. The problem was with your conditions at if statements. You were not looking for an empty string, but for a string with one character - a white space (" " instead of ""). I would also recommend getting used to === instead of ==. You can read more about that here: 
https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a

I'll post the corrected code as an edit on my answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(x === undefined || x === null || x.trim() === '') alert('Please enter a username');
if(y === undefined || y === null || y.trim() === '') alert('Please enter a password');
```